# Lines meaning in google maps

Tags: google-maps

How I can find lines meaning in google maps? What [dashed lines](https://www.google.lt/maps/@41.8678285,43.2483896,15.5z) below means?

[image]

Comment: Just because you are question blocked on WebApps doesn't mean you can ask your off-topic questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dashed lines are border lines, in this case between the Imereti and Smatskhe-Javakheti regions in Georgia.
The thinner dashed line is a trail/hiking path, as a switch to the satellite images shows.[image]